# Trix using rails actiontext add pure html

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, trix, actiontext

I would like to use the rich text editor trix in rails6. How can I add a button to trix which adds html content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow ActionText showing raw HTML, try this.

`<%= raw your_action_text_object.to_plain_text %>`

btw, I don't know why you want to add a button, could you explain in detail?

Comment: I'm interested too in a button that permits to paste html inside the trix input. For example to add a link (as <a href="...">foo</a>) copied from other pages html.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to do it using javascript, when clicking on a button, you'll need to fetch the rich_text element and then apply the raw html, as follows:

```
const element = document.getElementById('your-id-here')
element.editor.loadHTML('<div>HTML<br>HERE</div>')
```

font: https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/344#issuecomment-261939749