# How to truncate ActionText output without trix formatting info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, actiontext

I have a Rails Action Text field `:content` and it renders fine if I accept the entire field but it's long and I just want to display a part of it.

`<%= year.content %>` works fine except it's too long.

`<%= year.content.truncate(70) %>` results in `undefined method 'truncate' for #<ActionText::RichText:0x00007ffb811a6060>`

`<%= year.content.to_s.truncate(70) %>` displays `<div class="trix-content"> <div> <strong>Jack Marietich, restaura...` which I could work with, but is there a method that I don't have to strip the beginning?

Answer (score 10):

[Trix using rails actiontext add pure html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62858681/trix-using-rails-actiontext-add-pure-html?rq=1) which showed up after I posted but not before.

```
<%= year.content.to_plain_text.truncate(70) %>
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionText/RichText.html#method-i-to_plain_text but even if I had found it, not sure I would have understood that this is what I needed.

Comment: truncation should be done at the model level with a public method

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this for a preview, you can strip tags and then truncate. Something like this:

```
<%= truncate(strip_tags(year.content.to_s), length: 70) %>
```

Not that I'm advocating for monkey-patching, but this seems like it might be a good candidate for adding a custom method if this is something you plan on using often.

Comment: Thanks, that does work, but the answer below is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep the styling, yet truncate the content (followed by a 'read more' or alike), check out the following css:

```
.line-clamp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3; // number of lines
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  overflow: hidden;
}

<div class="line-clamp">
 <%= year.content %>
</div>
```

You can then use some basic JS toggle to remove the line-clamp class to reveal the rest of the content.